# Separating a tcolorbox into two columns

Tags: tcolorbox, two-column

I have a lovely colorbox with a text I want to separate into two columns One with Dung and the other with Labelling and, why not adding a bar in the middle:

[image]

Do you know how can I do that ? Many thanks in advance ! Here is the reproducible code at the moment :

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=admissible set]
\textbf{Dung}
S is an admissible set 

$\Leftrightarrow

\begin{cases}
S \mbox{ is conflict-free}\\
S \subseteq F(s) \mbox{ : S defends at least itself}
\end{cases}$

\textbf{Labelling}

an admissible labelling is a $\mathbb L$ without argument illegally in and illegally out
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package for an easy solution:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=admissible set]
  \begin{multicols}{2}
\textbf{Dung}
S is an admissible set 

$\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
S \mbox{ is conflict-free}\\
S \subseteq F(s) \mbox{ : S defends at least itself}
\end{cases}$
\columnbreak

\textbf{Labelling}

an admissible labelling is a $\mathbb L$ without argument illegally in and illegally out
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]